# SQL GROUP_CONCAT query assistance

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some problems figuring out the best use of GROUP_CONCAT.  In the query below I am trying to select multiple images from JAM_Plot_Images and set them against single records.  So get record 1, display image1.jpg, image2.jpg in each row.  Then get record 2, display image3.jpg, image4.jpg in the 2nd row and so on.

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(JAM_Plot_Images.image ORDER BY JAM_Plot_Images.image) AS images
FROM JAM_Plots
LEFT JOIN JAM_Plot_Images ON JAM_Plots.page_id = JAM_Plot_Images.page_id 
GROUP BY JAM_Plots.page_id
```

The problem I have is if a row has no images in a row it breaks the unique identifier when outputting the records, but only for that record.  So if records 1 2 and 4 have images it will output everything fine, but if record 3 has no image the unique ID won't appear.  NULL values appear within phpmyadmin output.  I have tried to use COALESCE to fix the issue but can't quite get it to work.

Comment: Please share sample input and output which you've tried and the expected output for a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: So if its `NULL` you want to replace with zero or empty?

Comment: If you want to remove the rows that has no image, you can use an `INNER JOIN`. But actually you didn't tell what should be the expected output

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` returns null values for all the columns from the second table when there's no match.

Comment: What unique identifier are you talking about? Do you mean `page_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with `GROUP_CONCAT()`, it's a general problem with `LEFT JOIN` when you have duplicate column names between tables.

Since you have the same column name `page_id` in both tables, both of them will be selected in the results. But when there's no images, `JAM_Plot_Images.page_id` will be `NULL`.

To disambiguate them, you should give an alias to `JAM_Plots.page_id`, and use that.

```
SELECT *, JAM_Plots.page_id AS jp_page_id, GROUP_CONCAT(...)
...
```